# How to filter the data using range slider in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to try filter the data using mat slider which is part of angular material.

I am sharing some snapshot of my code please help what code should be write to filter the data.

```
 pipe.filter.ts

    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Pipe({
      name: 'filterPrice'
    })
    export class FilterPricePipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
      }
    
    }




cryptocurrencies.component.html  
    
           <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="range" [(ngModel)]="pricesearch">
                    </div>
        
          <tbody *ngIf="alldata">
                    <tr (click)="displaycheckbox()" 
                        *ngFor="let latestdata of alldata  |  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p } | filter: filterPrice">
                        <td><input (click)=" validcheck(latestdata)" class="box" type="checkbox" [hidden]="showcheckbox">
                        </td>
                        <td>{{latestdata.cmc_rank}}</td>
                        <td>{{latestdata.id}}</td>
                        <td><img class="coin" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/{{latestdata.id}}.png"></td>
                        <td>{{latestdata.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{latestdata.symbol}}</td>
                        <td>${{latestdata.quote.USD.price.toFixed(2) | number: '2.'}}</td>
                        <td>${{latestdata.quote.USD.market_cap.toFixed(0) | number: '2.'}}</td>
                        <td>${{latestdata.quote.USD.volume_24h.toFixed(0) | number: '2.'}}</td>
                        <td>{{latestdata.circulating_supply.toFixed(0) | number: '2.'}}&nbsp;{{latestdata.symbol}}</td>
                        <td>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a sample project in stackblitz.com?

Comment: No, Because all data has come from external server.